# how many 7400 can the 74LS04 safely drive

Tags: ttl

how many 7400 can the 74LS04 safely drive ?

74LS04 Specs :

I output low  : 8 mA

7400 Specs :

I input low : -1.6 mA

PS : I know that the answer either 5 or 2. The only thing I am not sure is that do you consider each input for 7400 separately or not. So each 00 would need 3.2 mA or only 1.6 mA ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a bit of a trick question. If both the 7400 inputs are tied together, the total current draw when low will still be 1.6mA, as should be obvious from the schematic below.

[image]

The same can **not** be said of many other gates such as, say, 7402.

[image]

So you can drive any combination of individual inputs **or** pairs of inputs on the same gate that add up to 5 total. Trivially, if you hold the other input low the gate does not draw any current (nor will the output change). I don't think your question is stated unambiguously enough to give a numeric answer, but if you read the problem statement carefully you should be able to figure it out with this major clue.

Comment: I agree..  beat me by a minute... ..distracted by MotoGP replays in Spain

Comment: Although I would always say the fanout is 5 because any designer known it is redundant to drive both.